# Laravel: Getting the selected value of a dropdown list

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, declaration, laravel-5

I want to get the selected value of the a dropdown list.

The dropdown list contains a table from my database

**Here's my dropdown list**

```
 <div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('student_name', 'Assign a Student to this section:') }}
        {{ Form::select('firstname', $users, null) }}
</div>


<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('teacher_name', 'Assign a Teacher to this section:') }}
        {{ Form::select('firstname', $users1, null) }}
</div>
```

**Now, I want to get the selected value**

**Here's where I insert my record**

```
        foreach(User::where('isTeacher', '0')->where('isAdmin', '0')->get() as $student) 
        foreach(User::where('isTeacher', '1')->where('isAdmin', '0')->get() as $teacher)

        $section = new Section1();
        $section->name = Input::get('name');
        $section->student_id = $student->id;
       $section->student_firstname = $student->firstname;
       $section->teacher_id = $teacher->id;
       $section->teacher_firstname = $teacher->firstname;
```

You may be thinking why i use the *foreach*.
So far, im using my past codes as my reference to  create  users and it works great.

Now, Im using it again to record a section.

If you can suggest me other codes other than my foreach I would gladly appreciate it :)

Please help guys T_T  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your selections. They are currently both `firstname` - but they should be `student_name` and `teacher_name`:

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('student_name', 'Assign a Student to this section:') }}
        {{ Form::select('student_name', $users, null) }}
</div>


<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('teacher_name', 'Assign a Teacher to this section:') }}
        {{ Form::select('teacher_name', $users1, null) }}
</div>
```

Then in your code - you can get the selected name with this

```
$student_name = Input::get('student_name');
$teacher_name = Input::get('teacher_name');
```

Comment: @Virgil Cruz - did that help with your question? Do you need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to have the selected list items as "selected"?

like:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
  <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
```